# Prepared Statement Not Escaping Apostrophe

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am using JDBC connection object obtained from hibernate to perform bath update, I am doing this because I need to use the MySql ON DUPLICATE feature. But, when trying to insert I am not able to inset saying the string has special characters,

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
PreparedStatement pstm = null;
Connection conn = session.connection();

try
{
    IRKeyWordTweet record = null;
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    for (Iterator itrList = statusToInsert.iterator(); itrList.hasNext();) 
    {   
        try
        {
            record = (IRKeyWordTweet) itrList.next();
            pstm = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("INSERT QUERY");

            System.err.println(record.getTwtText());

            //tweetId
            pstm.setLong(1, record.getTweetId());

            Setters For Prepared statement....
            pstm.addBatch();
            int[] updateCounts = pstm.executeBatch();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    log.error("Exception Occured",e);
}
finally
{   
    try 
    {
        pstm.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    session.close();
}
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: You've omitted one of the most important parts: the SQL itself.

Comment: Another important thing: you didn't include your setters for the prepared statement.

Comment: I don't know if I upvoted that because it's @Jon Skeet or because he has a point :)

Comment: Show us the query where you have the escape.

Comment: You don't show us the part of the code that could contain the bug: the actual query, and the way you bind the parameters. Moreover, why don't you simply use session.createSQLQuery()?

Comment: I am not using session.SQLQuery() because I want to use the batch update feature, the number of records to be inserted is very high and I want to check the performance using batch update feature and at the same time avoid Duplicate entries. Not near my pc will update query soon.

Answer (score 9):

To escape single quotes, you can use JDBC's escape sequence:

```
Statement statement = 
statement.executeQuery(
  "SELECT * FROM DATA_TABLE  WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE 'Having\'s Quotes%' {escape '\'}");
```

The `{ escape '\'}` informs the JDBC driver to translate the `'\'` character to the database-specific escape character.

Helpful link [here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=8881)

Also, if you use a PreparedStatement, you don't even have to escape!

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DATA_TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE ?%");
ps.setString(1, "Having's Quotes");
```

Comment: Using prepared statements properly eliminates the need to escape manually.

Comment: thanks Kal.. but I want to use PrepareStatement for exactly the same reason.