# Prepared statements and Escaping

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I've read many times over - and just want to clarify (I think I'm confused)

I switched to mysqli today, and started using prepared statements.

*Example of my prepared statement*

```
function read($table, $var) {
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE `uid`=?")) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $table, $var);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        return mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt);
    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript>">alert("Something went wrong");</script>';
    }
}

$info = read("users", $_SESSION['uid']);
$char = read("characters", $_SESSION['uid']);
```

Do i still need to escape anything? I know, i know, i've read it everywhere that you dont need to escape when using prepared statements, but then there are questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181160/pdo-mysql-prepared-statements-not-escaping-characters) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176683/prepared-statement-not-escaping-apostrophe) that make me worried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the only problem with you query is that you cannot pass the tableName as a paramater. *Only values can be parameterized*. So the other way is to concatenate the tableName along with your query.

```
"SELECT * FROM `" . $tableNameHere . "` WHERE `uid`=?"
```

Comment: is this subject to injection?

Comment: if the **downvoter** could explain how `tableName` can be parameterized, i'll delete this answer.

Comment: see [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table name as parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter) and [Which tokens can be parameterized in PDO prepared statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622521/which-tokens-can-be-parameterized-in-pdo-prepared-statements)

Comment: Thank you for the links. Does this mean it's safe to enter in table names into the query?

Comment: @Wulf unfortunately, you still need to manually sanitized it. adding backticks around the table name may help prevent from the attack but I cannot fully guarantee it.

Comment: @Wulf: It's as subject to SQL injection as any query that doesn't escape interpolated data.  You might want to ensure that the table name doesn't contain any wacky chars, and/or is actually the name of a table. (`mysqli_real_escape_string` works for values, but identifiers follow slightly different rules.  In particular, they are delimited by backticks, which `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't escape.)

Comment: @cHao `mysqli_real_escape_string` still doesn't fully protect your from the attack. see the this article: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: As long as I am the one who defined the variable $table = "blah"; (in the page.php, it will be alright because the user won't be able to edit the variable, correct?

Comment: @JW.: People love to trot that old horse around.  In order for properly sanitized data to get around it, though, you need to (1) be using an old version of mysql, *and* an old version of the mysql libs, *and* (2) not tell mysql which charset you're using, *and* (3) be using one of the vulnerable character sets (which no one outside of China does).

Comment: @Wulf: If you set `$table`, and it's not from user input, it's safe.

Answer (score -1):

Well, first of all this code just won't work.

So, there are 2 questions actually

> 1. Do I need to do any additional escaping on the bound parameters

No.

> 2. How to safely insert an identifier into query?

It depends. As long as you have your table name hardcoded in your code - it's ok to insert it as is.
But if it's coming from the untrusted source, you have to filter it out, using whitelisting. 
I've explained it in my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8255054/285587

As for the questions you linked to, the second one is irrelevant and first one just makes very little sense. LIKE is *supposed* to return many rows, so, one have to either use no LIKE at all or worry not about it (in terms of safety). Though in terms of returning correct result you may want to escape characters that have special meaning in LIKE, but I wouldn't use LIKE for the search purposes at all.

Comment: I do not understand your last paragraph one bit... what's "LIKE"? Are you referring to the questions I posted?